# pairing parameters in PBC library

Tags: pairings

I would like to know what are the pairing parameters of PBC library and what are they used for? [Here](https://crypto.stanford.edu/pbc/manual/ch02s01.html) an example where they are used.

I noticed that we can give any file in the param subdirectory. Is there any difference or change if we use one file unstead of another?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the parameters define which curve is used, which has consequences on security and efficiency.

To decide which curve type you need, go to section 8 of the PBC manual and read the paper ["pairings for cryptographers"](http://eprint.iacr.org/2006/165)

then PBC provides functions to create your curve (i.e. param files):
https://crypto.stanford.edu/pbc/manual/ch05s01.html

But you can skip this step by directly using one of the curves already provided in the `param` directory.

Comment: The parameters not only define the curve (Type and parameters), but also the field/group with its order(s) through over which the curve is defined.